# What's $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}$?

Tags: summation

How do you calculate $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}$? And doesn't the sum terminate when  2k exceeds n, so the upper bound should be less than n?

EDIT: I don't understand the negging. Have I violated a rule of conduct or something?

Comment: "Have I violated a rule of conduct?" Well, technically... you're supposed to show effort every time you ask a question, so some people will just automatically downvote unless you include your own attempt in the question.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, $\dbinom{n}{m} = 0$ if $m > n$. Hence, $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{2k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\dbinom{n}{2k} = \sum_{\substack{0 \le m \le n \\ m \ \text{is even}}}\dbinom{n}{m}$.

To help you calculate the sum, note that by the binomial theorem:

$2^n = (1+1)^n = \displaystyle\sum_{m = 0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{m}1^m = \sum_{\substack{0 \le m \le n \\ m \ \text{is even}}}\dbinom{n}{m} + \sum_{\substack{0 \le m \le n \\ m \ \text{is odd}}}\dbinom{n}{m}$

$0 = (1-1)^n = \displaystyle\sum_{m = 0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{m}(-1)^m = \sum_{\substack{0 \le m \le n \\ m \ \text{is even}}}\dbinom{n}{m} - \sum_{\substack{0 \le m \le n \\ m \ \text{is odd}}}\dbinom{n}{m}$.

Do you see how to finish?

Comment: Yes, I do, I think. We add the two lines. But there's a bit I don't get. I don't understand how you got the floor bit. I knew the upper bound would be less than n but didn't know how to see what it was. How do you do/see this? Thanks.

Comment: We only need to sum over $k$ such that $0 \le 2k \le n$, i.e. $0 \le k \le n/2$. So, the upper bound is the largest integer less than or equal to $n/2$, i.e. $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Recall that each binomial coefficient is the sum of the two above it in Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose 2k}:\ {\large ?}}$

> $$
> \mbox{Note that}\quad\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose 2k}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\color{#c00000}{\large\infty}}{n \choose 2k}.
> $$

$$
\mbox{We'll use the identity}\quad
{m \choose s}=\oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ =\ a}
{\pars{1 + z}^{m} \over z^{s + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,,\quad s \in {\mathbb N}
$$

> Then,
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose 2k}}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{2k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{1 \over z^{2}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
> {1 \over 1 - 1/z^{2}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,z \over \pars{z - 1}\pars{z + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&={\pars{1 + 1}^{n}\times 1 \over 1 + 1}=\color{#66f}{\large 2^{n - 1}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{2k}=2^{n-1}-1$$

BECAUSE:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{2k}=\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+\binom{n}{3}+ \dots$$

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$

$$x=1,y=1: \sum_{k=0}^n  \binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}+ \dots=2^n$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{2k}-1=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}}{2}-1=2^{n-1}-1$$

Comment: How did you calculate it?

Comment: look at my edited answer.

Comment: Could you explain the second equality in the last line, please?

Comment: At the second sum ,k takes all numbers from 1 to n,at the first only the multiples of two,so  the second is 2 x the first.

Comment: Thanks I still don't get, though. If it was 3k would we able to use the same justification?

Comment: If you were summing up every 3rd binomial coefficient, then you have to do something slightly different. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875153) for details.

Comment: Where do you get $\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose 2k} = {n\choose 2}+{n\choose 4}+{n\choose 3}+\ldots$ from??  And yeah, the second equality in the last line makes literally no sense - there's no innate reason to believe that the half of the coefficients you remove will be equal to the half that you don't remove.  The _result_ is correct (I believe), but the reasoning to get there is entirely specious.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks, I thought I was missing something.

Comment: That third coefficient should be $\binom{n}{6}$. Also, the fourth line should also include the coefficient $\binom{n}{0}$.