# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{C_{2k-1}^{2n-1}}{2k})=\frac{2^n-1}{n+1}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

In my book it states that $\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{C_{2k-1}^{2n-1}}{2k})=\frac{2^n-1}{n+1}$, where C is binomial coefficient. To try and prove this I did:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{C_{2k-1}^{2n-1}}{2k})=\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{C_{2k-1}^{2n-1}}{2k})-(\frac{2n-1}{2})=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n (C_{2k}^{2n})-(\frac{2n-1}{2})$$

And here the summation simplifies to $2^{2n-1}$:
$$\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n (C_{2k}^{2n})-(\frac{2n-1}{2})=\frac{1}{2n}(2^{2n-1})-(\frac{2n-1}{2})$$
And finally it simplifies to:
$$\frac{2^{2n-1}-2n^2-n}{2n}$$
I have tried every way I could think of to try and simplify this to $\frac{2^n-1}{n+1}$ but I couldn't manage it. Am I missing a way to simplify it or did I mess somewhere before? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: It turns out my assumption that the top index of the binomial coefficient was 2n-1 was incorrect, it is actually n which gives you the correct answer.

Comment: it might help to know that $2^n=\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{n}{k})$ where $(\frac{n}{k})$ is the binomial coefficient

Comment: But thats what I did right? When I expanded the sum I got $C_{0}^{2n}+C_{2}^{2n}+C_{4}^{2n}+....$ which adds up to half of $2^{2n}$ or $2^{2n-1}$

Comment: what is $\frac{C_{2k-1}}{2k}$?

Comment: $C_{2k-1}$ is the binomial coefficient, or the combination formula (nCr), another representation is ${{2n-1} \choose {2k-1}}$. In my book the top part (2n-1) is not explicitly shown which is why I didn't include it here. Edit: I have now added it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I came across this problem in Binomial Theorem. I need help in proving this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982894/i-came-across-this-problem-in-binomial-theorem-i-need-help-in-proving-this) It seems that your guess for the missing argument was not the right one.

Comment: Yes that is true, using this does get the correct answer, but it doesn't feel right, after all how can it be n instead of 2n-1? When you put k = n you get $C_{2n-1}^n$ which means that the bottom index is larger than the top one, which I thought can't be possible? Anyways thank you for finding this, I am not sure why it didn't show up in the suggestions.

Comment: When $n<k,$ $\binom nk=0$ by definition. I found this post [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20(%5Cfrac%7BC_%7B2k-1%7D%7D%7B2k%7D)%3D%5Cfrac%7B2%5En-1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%24&p=1)