# Use the binomial theorem to derive a closed form expression for ${n \choose 0} + {n \choose 4} + {n \choose 8} +...+{n \choose 4⌊n/4⌋}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Use the binomial theorem to derive a closed form expression
for $${n \choose 0} + {n \choose 4} + {n \choose 8} +...+{n \choose 4⌊n/4⌋}$$
And I should use imaginary numbers right?

Comment: Should that last term be $\dbinom{n}{4\lfloor\tfrac{n}{4}\rfloor}$?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Start with $(1+x)^n = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x^k$, and plug in $x = 1,i,-1,-i$. This will give you four equations. What do you get when you add these four equations together and divide by $4$?

Also see [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875153/).

Comment: +1 Very clever solution! Can it be generalized when $4$ is replaced by another integer? EDIT: answer in the link you provided.