# Some Basic induction help.

Tags: induction

Let  $r\in \Bbb R$ such that  $r + \frac{1}{r}\in \Bbb N$, Prove by induction that $r^n + \frac{1}{r^n}\in \Bbb N$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$.

I've done some expansions for $(r+\frac{1}{r})^n$ for $n = 2,3$ and I can see how it holds.

I am having trouble showing it for all $n.$

Comment: That is wrong for $r=1/2$, since $r+1/r=5/2\not\in\mathbb N$. Also, please tell us what you tried so far once you got the correct problem statement.

Comment: Is this right? If you let $r=0.1$, then $0.1 + \frac{1}{0.1} = 10.1$.

Comment: I guess you mean more of "suppose $r +1/r \in \mathbb{N}$"?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936479/proving-that-frac-phi4001-phi200-is-an-integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $r^n+\frac{1}{r^n} \in \mathbb{N}$ for some $n \ge 1$.
Then
$$\left(r^n+\frac{1}{r^n}\right)\left(r+\frac{1}{r}\right) = r^{n+1} + \frac{1}{r^{n+1}} + r^{n-1} + \frac{1}{r^{n-1}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is $(r + \frac{1}{r})^2 $? You can multiple this by $r + \frac{1}{r}$ and get what you want for $n = 3$. Adopt this for general case.