# Induction: If $a+1/a$ is an integer, then so is $a^t+1/a^t$ for $t\in\mathbb N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

> $a$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ but not equal to $0$, and $a+\dfrac{1}{a}$ is integer, $a^t+\dfrac{1}{a^t}$ is also an integer for all $t\in\mathbb N$.

If $\displaystyle a+\frac1a$ is an integer then $\displaystyle \left(a+\frac1a\right)^2,\left(a+\frac1a\right)^3, \ldots $ are integers.

Maybe induction on $$a^{t+1} + \frac1{a^{t+1}} = \left(a^t+\frac1{a^t}\right)\left(a+\frac1a\right) - \left(a^{t-1}+\frac1{a^{t-1}}\right)$$

I'm having a problem doing the induction for this problem, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're basically done already. The right-hand side is a difference of two integers (by inductive hypothesis), so it's an integer.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Ah, but how do we know that $\left(a^t+\frac1{a^t}\right)$ is an integer?

Comment: By induction hypothesis

Comment: HINT: If $a+1/a= b$ then $a^2+1/a^2=b^2-2$ and $a^3+1/a^3=b^3-3b.$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that $\frac{\phi^{400}+1}{\phi^{200}}$ is an integer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936479/proving-that-frac-phi4001-phi200-is-an-integer)

Comment: @GCab Set it equal to whatever integer you want and you get a quadratic equation in $k$ with real roots if $k\geq 2$.

Comment: @GCab in the proof question, a is an element of Real numbers.

Comment: @Monkleys: actually $t$ can be in $\mathbf Z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct. The inductive hypothesis is "$(a^i+a^{-i})$ is an integer for all $i \leq t$". You will use this three times in each induction step: for $i=t$, for $i=1$, and for $i=t-1$.