# Finding the family of functions given an equation

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I played with the solution for the problem $$\text{if }\; x + \frac{1}{x} = a$$ what is $$x^5 + \frac{1}{x^5}$$
I tried different exponents other than 5 and tried finding the solution to it. I defined $f(x) = a^x + \frac{1}{a^x}$. I got $f(x + y)=f(x)f(y) - f(x-y).$ I tried reversing the equation I got to get $f(x)$ but I only got these:
$$f(0) = 2$$ by substituting $b=0$
$$f(x)=f(-x)$$
$$(f(a)^2 - 4)(f(b)^2 - 4) \geq 0$$
$$f'(0)=0$$
Can this be solved using the given information? Is $f(x) = a^x + \frac{1}{a^x}$ the only solution? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I already got the solution for $x^5 + \frac{1}{x^5}$, I'm asking if how can I get the family of functions $f(x)$ from $f(x + y)=f(x)f(y) - f(x-y)$, sorry for the unclear question

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936479/proving-that-frac-phi4001-phi200-is-an-integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left(x^3+\dfrac1{x^3}\right)\left(x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}\right)=x^5+\dfrac1{x^5}+x+\dfrac1x$$

Now $x^3+\dfrac1{x^3}=\left(x+\dfrac1{x}\right)^3-3\left(x+\dfrac1{x}\right)$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Expand
$$
\left(x+\frac{1}{x} \right)^5
$$
and the problem will suddenly become super easy.

Comment: I wouldn't call it _super_ easy. You still have at least one more step of actual thinking to do.

Comment: Well, you're right. But when you have the expanded form, you basically immediately see what you have to do.