# Where's my misstep in this trigonometric problem?

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\begin{align}
> \tan\alpha+\cot\alpha=\sqrt{ 6 } \\
> \tan^6\alpha+\cot^6\alpha= \ ?
> \end{align}$$

The given answer is $52$, but I got $214$ instead:

\begin{align} \tan\alpha+\cot\alpha=\frac{1}{\sin\alpha \cos\alpha}&=\sqrt{ 6 } \\ \\
\tan^6\alpha+\cot^6\alpha=\frac{\sin^6\alpha}{\cos^6\alpha}+\frac{\cos^6\alpha}{\sin^6\alpha}&= \\
 \\
\frac{\sin^{12}\alpha+\cos^{12}\alpha}{\sin^6\alpha \cos^6\alpha}&= \\
\\
\frac{(\sin^3\alpha)^4+(\cos^3\alpha)^4}{\sin^6\alpha \cos^6\alpha}&= \\
 \\
\frac{1-2\sin^6\alpha \cos^6\alpha}{\sin^6\alpha \cos^6\alpha}&= \\ \\
\frac{1}{\sin^6\alpha \cos^6\alpha}-2&= \\ \\
(\sqrt{ 6 })^6-2=216-2&=214
\end{align}

I know my method is not the most efficient, but my question is: what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: $(\sin^3\alpha)^4+(\cos^3\alpha)^4\ne1-2\sin^6\alpha \cos^6\alpha.$

Comment: This answers "your question" [Solution to two non polynomial equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524359/solution-to-two-non-polynomial-equation). Well, not your true question, which was already answered in the previous comment, but the question of your exercise: it gives you several methods (set $x=\tan\alpha$). You will find other such "duplicates" [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5E6%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E6%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: Please excuse me: I just rolled back the two last formattings because the previous version was easier to read (more space between the lines of formulas). This made the mistake easier to detect.

Comment: @ OP [another method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2710045/386889) is to calculate the two solutions $x_1,x_2$ of $x+1/x=\sqrt6$ (which is a quadratic equation in disguise) and then evaluate $x_1^6+x_2^6.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is Correct :**

Let $\tan \alpha = x$ , then $\cot \alpha = 1/x$

$$x+1/x=\sqrt{6}$$

Squaring , we get :

$x^2+2+1/x^2=6$

$x^2+1/x^2=4$

Cubing , we get :

$x^6+3x^4/x^2+3x^2/x^4+1/x^6=64$

$x^6+3(x^2+1/x^2)+1/x^6=64$

$x^6+12+1/x^6=64$

$x^6+1/x^6=52$

$$\tan^6 \alpha + \cot^6 \alpha = 52$$

**Where you went wrong :**

This is totally suspicious :
[image: wrong]

Comment: The OP did not ask for a solution but for a detection of their mistake. The last sentence of the original version was: "I know it is not the most efficient way to solve this, but I certainly want to know what did I do wrong." It was answered in comment.

Comment: I have added the wrong Part now , which matches your Earlier Comment (of course) & the other Answer by user David , @AnneBauval , though , my thinking is that when the Comment already shows the wrong Part , it is unnecessary to type it again & showing the Correct Answer might be better !

Comment: I fully agree with "when the Comment already shows the wrong Part , it is unnecessary to type it again" and not with "showing the Correct Answer might be better ", especially when it is explicitely not asked for, and when there are many duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Try evaluating $(\sin^3\alpha)^4+(\cos^3\alpha)^4$ for $x=\frac\pi4.$
Then do the same for $1-2\sin^6\alpha \cos^6\alpha.$

$$ \sin\frac\pi4=\cos\frac\pi4=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}. $$
$$ \sin^6\frac\pi4=\cos^6\frac\pi4=\frac18. $$
$$\left(\sin^3\frac\pi4\right)^4=\left(\cos^3\frac\pi4\right)^4=\frac{1}{64}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval "To be honest." I should have spelled it out, but was lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we can see what happened with that failed step, we can provide further details about what went wrong.  An identity was misapplied.  If $\sin^3\alpha=\sin\beta, \cos^3\alpha\ne\cos\beta$.  The identity you attempted to use can be proved by completing the square:
$$\sin^4\alpha+\cos^4\alpha=\sin^4\alpha+2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha+\cos^4\alpha-2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha=$$$$(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha)^2-2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha=1-2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha$$

We can use the same method to correct that step.  If we add and subtract $2\sin^6\alpha\cos^6\alpha$, it becomes
$$\dfrac{\sin^{12}\alpha+\cos^{12}\alpha}{\sin^6\alpha\cos^6\alpha}=\dfrac{(\sin^6\alpha+\cos^6\alpha)^2}{\sin^6\alpha\cos^6\alpha}-2$$
If you wished to proceed from here, it appears you can arrive at an answer by completing the cube of $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha$.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everyone's help on this. It seems like I mistakenly tried to apply this Trigonometric Identity:
$$\sin^4\alpha+\cos^4\alpha=1-2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha$$

Like this, which is supposedly wrong:

$$\begin {align} \sin^{12}\alpha + \cos^{12}\alpha&=\\(\sin^3\alpha)^4+(\cos^3\alpha)^4&= 
1-2\sin^6\alpha \cos^6\alpha
\end{align}$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).