# Find the sum of $\binom{2007}{0}+\binom{2007}{4}+...+\binom{2007}{2004}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Find the sum of 
$$S=\binom{2007}{0}+\binom{2007}{4}+\binom{2007}{8}+...+\binom{2007}{2004}$$

**My work so far:**
$$(1+1)^n=2^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+...+\binom{n}{n}$$
$$(1-1)^n=0=\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}-...+(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}$$

Comment: I think there's a typo, how can 2007 be the last term? Shouldn't it be 2004 (a multiple of 4)?

Comment: @shardulc: Thank you!

Comment: Defining $f(x)=(1+x)^{2007}$, your sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{501}\dbinom n{4i}$ equals $\dfrac 14\bigg(f(1)+f(-1)+f(i)+f(-i)\bigg)$. Do you see why?

Comment: I think [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875153/finding-binomn0-binomn3-binomn6-ldots?rq=1), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868695/how-to-find-sums-like-sum-k-039-binom2005k), and [this](http://www.amotlpaa.org/mathclub/2005-10-27.pdf) may be useful. (Perhaps even [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965997000517) though I'm not sure.)

Comment: @shardulc Yes. In other words this may be a duplicate question.