# Another Binomial

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

It starts with the first row of n elements as 1  1  0  0  0 ...
For n = 5,
The 1st row is 1  1  0  0  0

The next row is generated as ith element = the sum of (i)th and (i-1)%nth elements of previous row.

So the generated rows are

1  2  1  0  0

1  3  3  1  0

1  4  6  4  1

2  5  10 10  5

7  7  15 20  15

....

My question is if exists an expression for the ith element of kth row

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_choose_k for example?

Comment: If I understood your post correctly, you are simply looking for an expression for
$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n{5k}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n{5k+i}$, where $i=0,1,2,3,4$.
Perhaps you can look at some similar questions on this site, like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868695/how-to-find-sums-like-sum-k-039-binom2005k).

Comment: @Martin Sleziak No,I don't think it's same. In this question, k is independent of n, can be any positive number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably closer to a comment rather then an answer, but it seems that [the comment I wrote above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968271/another-binominal?noredirect=1#comment4041812_1968271) needs to be expanded and clarified.

The number in the $n$-th row and $i$-th (where $i=0,1,2,3,4$) column of your table can be written as
$$a_{n,i} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \binom n{5k+i}.$$
This formally looks as an infinite sum, but notice that there are only finitely many non-zero terms.

Notice that the above definition makes sense for arbitrary $i$ (not only $0\le i \le 4$), but clearly we is periodic:
$$a_{n,i+5}=a_{n,i}.$$

From [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) we get
$$a_{n,i} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \binom n{5k+i} =
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \binom {n-1}{5k+i-1} + \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \binom {n-1}{5k+i} = a_{n-1,i-1} + a_{n,i}$$
which corresponds to your recurrent definition. (If we consider also $a_{n,i+5}=a_{n,i}$.)

---

**Example**

From your definition you get

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 \\
  2 & 5 &10 &10 & 5 \\
  7 & 7 &15 &20 &15 \\
 22 &14 &22 &35 &35 \\
 57 &36 &36 &57 &70 \\
 127&93 &72 &93 &127
\end{array}$$

If we look at the numbers [in the $9$-th row](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pascal%27s+triangle) of the [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) (i.e., $1$, $9$, $36$, $84$, $126$, $126$, $84$, $36$, $9$, $1$) then we can see that
\begin{align*}
127&=1+126\\
93&=9+84\\
72&=36+36\\
93&=84+9\\
127&=126+1
\end{align*}

---

So your problem is equivalent to determining
$$a_{n,i} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \binom n{5k+i}.$$

You can probably find more about sums of this type in other questions on this site, or elsewhere. I was able to find this: [How to find sums like $\sum_{k=0}^{39} \binom{200}{5k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868695/how-to-find-sums-like-sum-k-039-binom2005k)

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.